# Automatic cursor positioning in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, console, pycharm

When running your program in Pycharm, and you have an input function in the code such as **input("Type True or False")**. Is there a configuration setting or something to have the cursor automatically go into the console instead of having to always click in there manually?

Comment: There's one terrible hack if you want to try. Check the python module pyautogui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround: Enable `Floating Mode` in the console. The cursor will go there when the program runs.

Note: You can hide the floating console with `Shift+Escape`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple work-around.  It does not automatically place the cursor correctly.  That being said, Alt-4 will correctly place the cursor in the run window.  No mouse click required.

i.e.

to run the program: Shift F-10

then to move focus to console: Alt-4